# When onDestroy is not called, which lifecycle methods are called upon resurrection?

Tags: android

Android documentation about Activity says that onDestroy may not get called if the system kills your process to reclaim memory. 
My questions are

1. Is there a way (developer tool etc) to simulate this situation (no onDestroy) for testing?
2. Suppose my process is killed by the system to reclaim memory and user navigates back to my activity, what methods are called? Does onCreate get called again?

Answer (score 0):

onDestroy simply isn't guaranteed to be called. In both situations everything has to be created again... so onCreate, onStart etc. You don't need a tool - if its some code that MUST run, don't put it there. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29